# Browser caching and Image optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, caching

Browser caching not enabled for all resources.

Not enabled for this domain

Not enabled for third party resources

This domain:

```
https://www.s7arnews.com/feeds/posts/default/-/news?alt=json-in-script&max-results=6&callback=jQuery1102014881141134537756_1510067600388&_=1510067600389

https://www.s7arnews.com/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-scr
```

Browser caching not enabled from these domains called from this page:

```
apis.google.com
pagead2.googlesyndication.com
```

how can i fix this

and i Have many problem about Image optimization

[Image optimization Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idHG5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First you can not enable caching for domains you do not control. Second, use an image editor to export better compressed images.